# How to check if an variable is an class or id(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a jQuery plugin and i'm using a variable in it which can be an class or id. I dont want to use the . or # in the variable, so is there an way to check if an variable is a class or id.

Coudn't find anything on the web about this.

some of the code

```
var defaults = {
    trigger: ''         
};

var opt = jQuery.extend(defaults, opt);

jQuery(opt.trigger).click(function(){
//run code
});
```

Comment: A variable without `.` or `#`, would not be easy to distinguish. Tell us more about your case. How are you assigning the value to the variable, what does it contain, what will it reference on the DOM and give us some code, not a theoretical story.

Comment: cant give the code, because its an premium plugin ;) the var is used as an trigger to set of an event(click in this case).

Comment: I am not asking for the full code, I am asking for a stripped down case, which would let us understand what you want to achieve. Then you can take our free support and get rich with it as much as you want. ;)
**Update**: With your code, there is no way to tell 100% if it is one or the other. You are bound to fail on this guess.

Comment: a simple but working solution is found below :)

Comment: Sure, you will see what I mean you are bound to fail when your users start using the same id and class for their elements, like `<div id="user"></div>` which is `100px` on the left, and what they really wanted to modify is `<a class="user"></a>` `100px` on the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for

```
if($("#"+variable).length){
   //It is an id.
}
```

Comment: There might be two elements with the same class name and id. E.g. `<div id="left"></div>` and `<div class="left"></div>`.

Comment: if($("#"+variable).length) will only check for id and not class. Ids should always be unique on a page. If you have 2 elements with same id then you should first clean that up.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the uniqueness of the ids. It has to do with the ids and classes being the same, which is perfectly fine by the standards.

Comment: Simple but smart, simple check if the id excites...why didn't i think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right but if($("#"+variable).length) will only look for id and if($("."+variable).length) will only look for element with that class name.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName(your_vairable).length != 0){
    // It's a class
}
else if (document.getElementById(your_variable) != null){
    // It's an id
}
else{
   // Oh god what have you done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you scour the CSS on the page and match it to a class, but who's to say you can't identify something the same as a class name?

I would do something like (this is a function but you can apply to a plugin):

```
function passIdentifier(id, isClass)
{
    var selector;
    if (isClass)
    {
        selector = '.' + id;
    }
    else
    {
        selector = '#' + id;
    }
}
```